# Where is google guava cache storing values?..Is it safe to use it in EJB?

Tags: jakarta-ee, guava, google-guava-cache

In my web application I am using google guava cache to store the User details at the EJB level.

Just wondering if there can be any implication associated with doing so.?

Where is google guava cache storing its values ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guava Caches store values in RAM. See https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained#applicability.